# Why can't height:100% work?

Tags: html, css

this is my html:

```
<div class="head">hello</div>
<div class="main">nice</div>
```

I'd like `div.main`'s height to extend to the bottom of the page. I tried to set it's height to 100%, but it doesn't work:

```
.head{
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;
}
.main{
    background-color: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cVRvj/

Comment: Do you need the content past the stretched div? Or will the page have no scrollbar?

Comment: Have you even try to search?! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=height+100 About 10 possible duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the `html` and `body` to 100%. The `div` contained in them can only take as much as they do.

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

See here and a million other google results for "HTML height 100%": http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/howtoset100tableheightinhtml.aspx

Answer (score 3):

By default the `100% height` of `body`, `static div's` & `relative div's` means `100% height of this content.`

You can use `display:table` property for this

### http://jsfiddle.net/cVRvj/4/

*It's work till IE8 & above browsers*

**OR**

You can do like this

### http://jsfiddle.net/cVRvj/6/

*It's work in all browsers*

Answer (score 2):

Because it depends on the size of `html` and `body` sections. Try putting this in your css file:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cVRvj/3/

Answer (score 2):

technically it is working. It's 100% enough height to cover the background of nice. As others have said you have to set html, body to 100%

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I can think of is just force a largish size, say 400px
If it's bigger it will be ok.
Use both min-height and height to cover all browsers as IE doesn't know min-height historically.

```
.head{
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;
}
.main{
    background-color: green;
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, give the head a percentage to prevent scrolling.

```
html,body{ height:100%; }
.head{
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;
    height:5%;
}
.main{
    background-color: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 95%
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cVRvj/7/)

Answer (score 1):

If you set HTML and body tags to 100% too it will work.

```
html,body {
    height:100%;     min-height:100%;
}
```

Adding the min-height helps where the content is otherwise larger than 100% of the screen (i.e. you need to scroll down to see all the content). Without it, the `height:100%;` won't include the below-the-fold content.

Comment: You can set .main  margin-top:-30px;  (or whatever the height of head div is) to correct that.